# Attempt to read from a null array using Volley and GSON

Tags: android, gson, android-volley

I am using Volley in a music player I am trying make.

Here is how I define what a song is in my music player. I have this "song object" with some attributes

```
SongObject {

    public String albumArtURI;

    // Some other attributes 
}
```

To get `albumArtURI` I make a query for it. If the URI does not exist, I try to pull an image URL down from the internet, but I get this error:

> Attempt to read from a null array

So here is the code that gets the image url from the internet and assigns it to the song object

```
 if(songObject.albumArtURI != null){

                    // The URI exists, so we leave as is

                } else {

                    // The album art URI does not exist,
                    // so we try to pull an album art .jpg URL down from iTunes
                    ServiceHandler serviceHandler = new ServiceHandler(MainActivity.this);
                    serviceHandler.getJSON_URL();               

                    songObject.albumArtURI = serviceHandler.JSONObjectsList[0].artworkUrl30; 
                    // Throws error "Attempt to read from a null array"
                }
```

So as you can see from the above code, this line throws the error

```
songObject.albumArtURI = serviceHandler.JSONObjectsList[0].artworkUrl30; 
// Gives error "Attempt to read from a null array"
```

However, `serviceHandler.JSONObjectsList[0].artworkUrl30` should not be a null array.

And as one can see from the lines in the subsequent class, by using a print statment, the said variable is not null

```
Log.v("TAG",String.valueOf(JSONObjectsList[0].artworkUrl30)); 
// Prints http://is4.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Music6/v4/68/b5/27/68b5273f-7044-8dbb-4ad1-82473837a136/source/30x30bb.jpg
```

And here is the class itself:

```
public class ServiceHandler {

    Context ctx;
    SongInfo[] JSONObjectsList;
    String albumArtURI;
    String url = "https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=michael+jackson";

    public ServiceHandler(Context ctx){

        this.ctx = ctx;
    }

    public void getJSON_URL(){

        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(ctx);

        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(url, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                // If there is a response, do this
                if (response != null) {

                    // Get the number of JSON objects on the web-page
                    int resultCount = response.optInt("resultCount");

                    // If there is a JSON object on the web-page, do this
                    if (resultCount > 0) {

                        // Get a gson object
                        Gson gson = new Gson();

                        // Get a JSONArray from the results
                        JSONArray jsonArray = response.optJSONArray("results");

                        // If the array exists, do this
                        if (jsonArray != null) {

                            // Convert the JSONArray into a Java object array 
                            JSONObjectsList = gson.fromJson(jsonArray.toString(), SongInfo[].class);

                            // Prints http://is4.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Music6/v4/68/b5/27/68b5273f-7044-8dbb-4ad1-82473837a136/source/30x30bb.jpg
                            Log.v("TAG",String.valueOf(JSONObjectsList[0].artworkUrl30));                                                          
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.e("LOG", error.toString());
            }
        });

        requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
    }

    public class SongInfo {

        // Some attributes

        public String artworkUrl30;

        // Some more attributes
    }
}
```

So I think the problem is related to the asynchronous nature of the Volley?

Am trying to read an array before it's been "populated"?

Will the array eventually be populated when Volley is done doing its thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your assumption is correct, it's because of asynchronous. They array will have data when Volley is done with it's task (i.e. onResponse method is called and executed). You can use an interface to get the data from it.

Define an interface

```
public interface MyInterface {
    public void myTask (SongInfo[] songInfo)
}
```

then use the interface as parameter in your getJSON_URL method

```
getJSON_URL (MyInterface myInterface) {
...
@Override
public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
.....
myInterface.myTask(JSONObjectsList);
}
```

then in your main class

```
...
serviceHandler.getJSON_URL(new MyInterface);
@Override 
public void myTask (SongInfo[] songInfo) {
...
songObject.albumArtURI = serviceHandler.JSONObjectsList[0].artworkUrl30;
...
}
...
```

Comment: Thanks. Interestingly, when I do this `albumArtURI = JSONObjectsList[0].artworkUrl30;` in the service handler class, and then `songObject.albumArtURI = serviceHandler.albumArtURI;` in the main class, I don't get the "null array error". Would this strategy allow me avoid using an interface to get the job done? It seem like the interface is just there to avoid a compile error. Is that really all the interface is doing? Just helping me avoid a compile error?

Comment: No. You call the interface's method when volley is done with it's task (I.e. on response is executed). And I think you faced runtime error and not compile error?